# Is there any way to suppress error "Resource Group not found" for azurerm_resourcegroup data source in terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using azurerm_resource_group data source for fetching whether the resource group exists or not. But unfortunately I get an error "Resource Group "rerer4" was not found" when the resource group is not present. Is there any way to suppress this error, so that my terraform script can continue with the execution of rest of the script?

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
name = "rerer4"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not possible. Terraform Data Sources are not designed for that kind of check.

A possibility might be running the check outside Terraform, for example via a shell script with Azure CLI, and provide the result as an input variable to Terraform.

Comment: Ok .Thanks Simone for you help. We have already tried tried using cli, but we were looking for a solution using terraform functions. We will possibly go ahead with the cli based solution.